# Is it possible to redirect to youtube app?

Tags: react-native, youtube

I would like to know if is it possible to redirect to the Youtube app when I press a tab in a DrawerNavigator ?

For example if I have a DrawerNavigator with an item **Our Youtube Channel**, if I click on it, it will open the youtube App on a specific channel ? Does a specific library exists ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try for linking library

and use this code

```
Linking
.openURL( 'vnd.youtube://user/channel/' + channel_id )
.catch( ... )
```

For example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => {
      Linking.openURL( 'vnd.youtube://user/channel/' + channel_id );

          }}
        >
     <Text>Youtube channel</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This solution is based on the concept of openlink or deeplink.

Comment: please check the below solution also

Answer (score 3):

I use this code to open youtube channel

```
Linking.canOpenURL('vnd.youtube://channel/' + channelId).then(supported => {
   if (supported) {
      return Linking.openURL('vnd.youtube://channel/' + channelId);
   } else {
      return Linking.openURL('https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + channelId);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an another question about youtube. I want to show a playlist when I click on a `TouchableOpacity` but this time it's in the view. Does it works like deepLinking or ?

In concrete, I have a few images on top, and when i click on one of the image it will show me the playlist that is assigned to this image and a videoPlayer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a playlist you can try for

```
youtube://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgD9br3bze22iMSimpPeQ85CIqLswcklR
```

or

```
'vnd.youtube://playlist/list/' + playlist_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to redirect any Youtube channel => vnd.youtube://c/xyzchannel in Linkin.openUrl() from react-native.
For Example:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Linking.openURL('vnd.youtube://c/TariqMasoodOfficial')}>
   <Image
      source={require('../../assets/youtube1.jpg')}
      style={styles.footerImage}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I used youtube Image in TouchableOpacity to click. You can write your channel name right after 'c/' in a link.